# matlab - surf with 3 vectors

Tags: matlab

I got an assignment to make to fallowing function using 2 vectors and 2 parameters:

```
f2= ((cos(x)).^2/w2 + (sin(y)).^2/w3)*(-2*10^5+2.5*10^5);
```

I get a new vector which is kinda weird

if `w2=3,w3=5` and `x` is a vector from `1-10` and y is a vector from `2:2:20`.

I get this vector:

> -134331.694334541  -156930.983357435   -114422.587024547   -115454.347733941   -178496.698590187   -108777.226902904   -103570.802583501   -194091.395692804   -102621.044915812   -99656.4625498021

My question is how I use `surf` function on `f2`?

I am told to use `surf` on `f2`.
but when I try to use the `surf(x,y,f2)` I get an error saying `f2 needs to be a matrix`.

Any ideas? This is my code:

```
x=[1:10];
y=[2:2:20];
w2=3;
w3=5;

f2= -2*10^5+2.5*10^5*((cos(x)).^2/w2 + (sin(y)).^2/w3)
surf(x,y,f2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the assignment is looking something like this:

```
[newX,newY]=meshgrid(x,y);
f2= ((cos(newX)).^2/w2 + (sin(newY)).^2/w3)*(-2*10^5+2.5*10^5);
surf(newX,newY,f2);
```

Here, you calculate value of `f` for all combinations of `x` and `y` using `meshgrid`. Then you visualize them using `surf`.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but that was the problem.. didnt have the meshgrid. thanks!

Comment: @pelleg You could have written your own meshgrid.